# ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML' resolved method

Tags: pyyaml

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall
```

I resolved by below command:

```
$ pip install -U PyYAML               
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing ./.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc/PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyYAML
Successfully installed PyYAML-5.3.1


$ pip show PyYaml

Name: PyYAML
Version: 5.3.1
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: /home/ranger/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Comment: If you have solved this, maybe you could post as an answer?

Comment: I want, but the stackoverflow rejected me ……

Comment: We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by below command:

```
$ pip install -U PyYAML               
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing ./.cache/pip/wheels/e5/9d/ad/2ee53cf262cba1ffd8afe1487eef788ea3f260b7e6232a80fc/PyYAML-5.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyYAML
Successfully installed PyYAML-5.3.1


$ pip show PyYaml

Name: PyYAML
Version: 5.3.1
Summary: YAML parser and emitter for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml
Author: Kirill Simonov
Author-email: xi@resolvent.net
License: MIT
Location: /home/ranger/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -H pip3 install --ignore-installed PyYAML
```