# issue accessing clip-vit-large-patch14 in order to load HF model (python)

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning

I am trying to run some code to setup and load a model, keep getting this error:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/x/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--openai--clip-vit-large-patch14/refs/main'**

tried to create it directly in my terminal (mac m1) and now I am getting this error instead (**IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/x/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--openai--clip-vit-large-patch14/refs/main'**), not sure what I am supposed to do to avoid this error.

I have these loaded, gives no error and sd-v1-4.ckpt and sd-clip-vit-l14-img-embed_ema_only.ckpt under the models. Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information, I am new to this and not sure if I missed anything important! Thank you!

```
!pip3 install omegaconf
!pip3 install torch torchvision
!pip3 install pytorch-lightning
!pip3 install einops
!pip3 install lightning-bolts
!pip3 install --ignore-installed PyYAML #referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62402718/error-cannot-uninstall-pyyaml-resolved-method
!pip3 install taming-transformers-rom1504
!pip3 install git+https://github.com/openai/CLIP.git
!pip3 install transformers
!pip3 install kornia


from omegaconf import OmegaConf 
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from einops import rearrange
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel
from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config
from ldm.models.diffusion.ddim import DDIMSampler
from ldm.models.diffusion.plms import PLMSSampler
from ldm.invoke.devices import choose_torch_device
```

tried to create it directly in my terminal (mac m1) and now I am getting this error instead (**IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/x/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--openai--clip-vit-large-patch14/refs/main'**), not sure what I am supposed to do to avoid this error.